# Image wont appear inside div with text

Tags: html, css, web

Im trying to get an image to appear on the far right side of the div beside the text but it keeps appearing outside that area. i dont want to hardcode the margins in to force it to appear there. is there a property that will make it appear alongside the text that im missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .box{
                height: 80px;
                width: 400px;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 45px;
                font-family: Georgia;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <p style="max-width: 50%">Image<p>
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/plus-big-512.png" alt="imagedownload" width="15%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `.box` div `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 100%;`

make `img` width `50px`

So your code will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .box{
                height: 80px;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 45px;
                font-family: Georgia;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            img {
              width: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Image<p>
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/plus-big-512.png" alt="imagedownload">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, ok that was exactly what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: @jsie7 Glad to hear that. Kindly upvote the answer, thanks.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation on this account but ill upvote on my other account

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .box{
                height: 80px;
                width: 400px;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 45px;
                font-family: Georgia;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                display:flex;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <p style="max-width: 50%">Image<p>
                <img style="float:right" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/plus-big-512.png" alt="imagedownload" width="15%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```